# How can I return a person's information when they have the max(age) among others in neo4j?

Tags: c#, sql, database, neo4j, graph-databases

I am working on neo4j. My application is a Family tree. I want to return name and age for the oldest person on the family.

I used this Cypher Query to see the max age on the tree:

MATCH (n) WITH  MAX(n.age) as age return age.

Now, I want to get the n.name and n.age but I do not know how.

Could anyone help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To solve the problem, you must sort the nodes in descending order of age and take the first position:

```
MATCH (n)
RETURN n.name, n.age 
       ORDER BY P.age DESC // Sorting in decreasing order
       LIMIT 1             // Return the first node in the sequence
```

But what if we have people of the same age? Then our query returns incomplete information.

So the solution will be to calculate the maximum age and return all the nodes in which the property age is equal to this value:

```
MATCH (n) 
WITH MAX(n.age) as maxAge
MATCH (n) WHERE n.age = maxAge
RETURN n.name, maxAge
```

By the way, it's strange that you keep the age of the person. It is advisable to keep the date of birth.  If the date of birth is not known exactly, then store the year of birth or the interval of approximate birth years.

Comment: Thank you guys. That was helpful. It worked just fine and returns the thing I am looking for.